# What fundamental data structure is used to implement NSOrderedSet

Tags: objective-c, nsorderedset

NSOrderedSet seems to be able to give O(1) lookup speed of hash-tables and array like ordering of objects?  What is the data structure used to achieve this?  Is it a combination of two, e.g: Hashtable and a separate Array where index i has the key corresponding to it's object in the Hashtable?

Comment: I am trying to understanding objective-C concepts better to improve my programming.   What is wrong with asking such questions?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with asking.  However, SO is not the correct forum for such a question.

Comment: Can you point me to a rule that says that questions that have definite YES/No answer and can improve a person's understanding of a programming language are disallowed on SO?  The question here is simple, how would one implement something similar to NSOrderedSet.  Is there one fundamental data structure that achieves it or do we need a something more complex that involves multiple data structures.  I think it has a yes/no answer (i.e not a subjective question) and improves my CS knowledge.  I don't see any reason why it is disallowed on SO.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask

Comment: As I said, I don't think my Q is subjective.  From above page, example 1 of Constructive subjective questions:  "inspire answers that explain “why” and “how”.  The answer to this Q is "how is NSOrderedSet" implemented. Clear concise how answer.

Comment: Of course this is a valid question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We don't know how Apple chose to implement this data structure. The only way to find out would be to reverse-engineer the Foundation framework. But this is not an useful thing to do, Apple could change the implementation and underlying data structure with every update. So relying on this for a production app would be very stupid since it could break the app at any time.

If you wanted to implement this yourself your approach with a hash table and an array will work. The best way would be to store the objects in the array and have the hash map store the array indices keyed by objects.

Of course there are other possible ways how this could be implemented with different performance characteristics. It could be just an array making the containsObject: test O(n), or it could just be a hash table (with the object as key and index as value) making the objectAtIndex: operation O(n).

Comment: Thanks, Sven.  Do you know of any resource that shows the run-times for various operations with each of the built-in collection classes provided by Apple.  I.e in above case, something that definitively shows that NSOrderedSet has O(1) look up for both contains and objectAtX.  So, that we need to reinvent the wheel only when needed.

Comment: Or a binary search tree that overwrites duplicates